# How dangerous is Server Error in '/' Application.?

Tags: asp.net, runtime-error, server-error

I made this website of mine but now , someone E-mailed me and reported the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current 
custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the 
application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). 
It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be 
viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within 
a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the 
current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its 
"mode" attribute set to "Off".


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a 
custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the 
application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom 
error page URL.


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" 
defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
   </system.web>
```

I wanted to know is this dangerous for my website?Can it be used to hack my website?If yes , how?
I can't change anything because I don't have access to my website for the following 4 months.

Comment: Information that could be extracted: (1) you are using ASP.NET (2) you are not using .NET Core (3) you are using IIS as your webserver (4) Request ended in a runtime error. In short: an attacker could check some zero day exploits for IIS and the .NET framework

Answer (score 0):

In short: Its NOT dangerous, It does NOT give any information about the error, just that it happened. It might give some information about the type of server you have, but thats already probably in your server banner (and elsewhere). I would not worry about it.